# Code security questions on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking at developing an app to leverage the Google Doc side of Google Apps Scripts. I have a couple of questions about the security of Google Apps Scripts.

How easy is it for a user to copy the code from a shared Google Apps Script? Is there any way to prevent this?

Are there any plans to create a similar API for the Google App Engine for manipulating Google Documents( not just listing what documents are available) so that document manipulation could be done on the server side?

Is there a way planned to share out Google Apps Scripts per Google User or per group, and not just "Publish to the World" or "Within a domain" as is currently the case?

Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 0):

About copying the shared script: dont share it there is no need to share. Publish as webapp and share the url. Nobody can get to the script that way.

About opening the api: no plans that i know of (im not from google), but note that apps script does run server side.

The last one: publish to your domain and run as owner, then in your handler (Roget) use user services to tell the active user email. Use group services to see it she belongs to a group. If user shouldnt access show an access error.

Voila.

Comment: Hi Zig,  
Thanks for the reply.

Surely if you are logged in and running the script, you can download the source?

Comment: If I do "view source" in the brower I can see the javascript?

Comment: Yes I have I can see some javascript just need to know how much exposure of the underlying script this gives. So basically you're saying it's not the actual script itself that is in here? No offence to you, you have been a fantastic help, but I'd prefer to have someone official from Google to confirm.

Comment: Doubt google will confirm you here. Think about it, it just doesnt make sense from any point of view that gas server-side code is viewable from a client. Why would google do that if the code runs server-side not client side? Just doesnt make sense. At most you will see htmlservice/uiapp client side handlers but those just deal with ui manipulations and not any confidential data (its up to the dev but everyone knows not to put any confifential stuff like keys on client-side javascript.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but you understand if the company I'm working for want to commit time and money to developing a major new product on Google Apps Script, they need certainties, not educated guesses - and it's my neck on the line if I make a wrong recommendation.  We have tried through several different avenues to talk to someone from Google, and they all end up at Stack Overflow.  Not an appropriate forum for this kind of question in reality, but we have no other option.

Comment: If you look at the docs, they do talk about who has access to what. It would be a (major) bug if it did what you fear, and it would be a (major) failure from google to expose such bug to their millions of customers. So, no i dont think the bug happens and we have no evidence that it does. Im a moderador in the GAS add-ons g+ community if that helps.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for now, in the hope that someone from Google will see it.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: did you see my last reply? seems we posted at the same time.

Comment: @ZigMandel : I am also looking for same thing?  I have written a script inside script editor (Spread Sheet). So now everybody who use my spreadsheet can access the code (by going through script editor). Is there any way to disable or hide the scriptEditor or any other way to secure my script code  ? Any usefull link much appreciated

Comment: It seems that user services won't give you the user's e-mail if the script is running as the developer.  Ugh!

Comment: only gives it in a gapps domain